# Excel VBA Add-In - how to ensure that events are always captured; also after errors, resets, saves etc.?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently developing an add-in with various UDF's and subs for my workplace to ease the daily work. As part of this I need to capture the changes of these functions in any workbook that's open. The purpose is to check for potential errors.

I've currently done it with the help of a class (called `clsApp`) like this:

```
Option Explicit

' Class module
Public WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)

    '' Code to check for uncorrected errors which is the working case

End Sub
```

and a macro to instantiate the class:

```
Public myApp As clsApp

Public Sub Init()

    'Reset in case it's already loaded
    Set myApp = Nothing
    Set myApp = New clsApp
    Set myApp.app = Application

End Sub
```

and in `thisWorkbook` i'm calling the `init()` sub when opened:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Init
End Sub
```

However the value of the `myApp` object variable is sometimes lost or the events simply stops sending to the class - e.g. if an error occurs or if the "reset" / end button is clicked. Hence, after it's lost the events are never fired and therefore the subs to check for errors are never fired.

Is there any way to prevent this and make sure that the variable holding the class object is never lost?

Comment: @SiddharthRout thank you for the response - however as I'm using an Add-in I don't believe the `Workbook_SheetChange` events and so forth will fire anyways, if the user is working in another workbook?

Comment: True that. Deleted my comment

Comment: Perhaps a restart button in your Add-In bar (is there is one?)

Comment: @SiddharthRout oh but the first part of your answer was actually good, and would have suggested you put it in as an answer, as it's the best/only answer I've seen so far (if an answer states there is no solution to the issue, and if there isn't, it's still the correct answer). Also seems to coincide with what other people are stating on Microsofts forum (sadly). Regarding the restart button it's not a bad idea, but the problem is that the users have no experience with VBA and hence probably wouldnt know when and why to click it :)

Comment: Feel free to put it as an answer and accept it. I am still thinking if there is "any" way we could restart init...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Workbook_SheetCalculate event in your Addin to check if your myApp is nothing and if not set it again. 
You need to put a volatile function on a sheet in your addin like =Now()

so:
Your Module:

```
Public myApp As ClsApp

    Public Sub Init()
        If myApp Is Nothing Then
            Set myApp = New ClsApp
            Set myApp.app = Application
       End If
    End Sub
```

ThisWorkBook of your Addin:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Init
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Init
End Sub
```

It's still a workaround and it needs some sort of calculation to get reset again.

Comment: BTW I only think your myApp goes out of scope when an error occurs in the Addin itself (not in another workbook) so maybe you can add some error trapping in the addin to prevent going out of scope in the first place.